# Get new dictionary using filter in python

Tags: python, dictionary, filter

A have a dictionary like this:

```
dict = {
 'a':
    {'a1':(1,0,0,1,0), 'a2':(1,1,1,0,0)},
 'b':
    {'b1':(1,1,0,1,1), 'b2':(1,0,1,0,0)}
}
```

What I want is to make a new dictionary exactly like **dict** but without zeroes in a tuples

```
dict_new = {
 'a':
    {'a1':(1,1), 'a2':(1,1,1)},
 'b':
    {'b1':(1,1,1,1), 'b2':(1,1)}
}
```

The following is correct:

```
 >>> a = (1,0,0,1)
 >>> filter(lambda x: x!= 0,a)
 >>> (1,1)
```

So, what I am trying to do is

```
 dict_new = filter(
     lambda x: filter(
       lambda y: dict[x][y]!=0), dict[x]), dict)
```

But the answer is

```
['a', 'b']
```

What am I doing wrong? And is that possible to do things like this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to loop over the nested structure to apply the filters only to the inner values. Dict comprehensions work fine for that:

```
dict_new = {kouter: {kinner: tuple(filter(bool, vinner)) for kinner, vinner in vouter.iteritems()} 
            for kouter, vouter in dict_old.iteritems()}
```

Demo:

```
>>> {kouter: {kinner: tuple(filter(bool, vinner)) for kinner, vinner in vouter.iteritems()} 
...             for kouter, vouter in dict_old.iteritems()}
{'a': {'a1': (1, 1), 'a2': (1, 1, 1)}, 'b': {'b1': (1, 1, 1, 1), 'b2': (1, 1)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd rather have a loop than a dict comprehension:

```
>>> print adict
{'a': {'a1': (1, 0, 0, 1, 0), 'a2': (1, 1, 1, 0, 0)}, 'b': {'b1': (1, 1, 0, 1, 1), 'b2': (1, 0, 1, 0, 0)}}
>>> newdict = {}
>>> for k in dict:
...   newdict[k] = {}
...   for k2 in adict[k]:
...     newdict[k][k2] = filter(lambda x: x!=0, adict[k][k2])
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to keep the `1`s then you don't actually have to filter anything, you can just sum the sequence to get the number of `1`s and create a new one with that many `1`s in it.

```
dict_input = {
 'a':
    {'a1':(1,0,0,1,0), 'a2':(1,1,1,0,0)},
 'b':
    {'b1':(1,1,0,1,1), 'b2':(1,0,1,0,0)}
}

dict_output = {}

for key, subdict in dict_input.iteritems():
   dict_output[key] = {}
   for subkey, items in subdict.iteritems():
       dict_output[key][subkey] = (1,) * sum(items)
```